# How will the lack of ground stations affect navigation?

Tags: approach, traffic-pattern

VOR's and NDB beacons are getting closed day by day and they were used for making and then referencing the holding patterns and the entry procedures and how they were named.

So

- How will we make holding patterns and entries from now on? What will be base them from now and how will we name them?
- Will the GPS approaches replace other approaches? (Which will make GPS mandatory at least for Class B airspace I Guess)
- If GPS approaches doesnt replace them... Will the old names be kept for holding patterns and entries? Will we still say [RW29 VOR approach and missed entry procedures?](https://trvacc.org/images/Charts/LTBJ.pdf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GPS/WAAS will replace all but ILS in the end. Even now, with graphic displays, smart-lookup from databases, and a line to follow presented to the pilot, VOR use is rapidly falling by the wayside, and point to point navigation will become the norm (and that was occurring in 1996 even, I recall getting cleared direct to a waypoint that was off my paper chart and having to ask for a heading to put in the autopilot to fly the plane while I found it on the chart).  In my airplane, my AVIDYNE IFD-540 does all the work, and I have ILS for precision landings and VOR if needed. Nearby VORs are going away.  DME and ADF were pulled out of my plane years ago.

Comment: I'm kind of glad I lived through the VOR years, now that we know they're destined for the history books. Something to look back on with nostalgia, and admire the technology.

Comment: GLS/GBAS/LAAS will replace ILS. The issues with ILS are arguably worse than the issues with VOR.