# Will the IFR Grade GPS be an requirement in the future?

Tags: faa-regulations, gnss

[This question is directly related to my other question so I have to ask it](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64321/how-will-the-lack-of-ground-stations-affect-navigation)

I think its obvious why I ask this if you read that question but I will repeat myself again.

Station based navigation is **literally dying** and airspace is getting more crowded everyday.

So will the GPS be an FAA requirement in the future? I couldn't find it but I guess I am missing it.

I am just afraid of an future where people not finding approaches for airports which will limit them to the "backcountry" airports which still will have VOR DME and NDB.

Comment: *So will the GPS be an FAA requirement in the future?* It is a requirement **in 2020** with the ADS-B mandate. *For certain airspaces...

Comment: @RonBeyer That's true, but I think the question here is about an approach-capable GPS, rather than an ADS-B position source. There are 'cheaper' ADS-B solutions out there that don't provide any GPS display in the cockpit.

Comment: Why do you think "backcountry" airports even have instrument approaches?

Comment: @Pondlife That's why it was a comment, I figured that he means the requirement for an RNAV GPS source to drive the approach indicator. Many ILS approaches have RNAV publications with them, and I assume that we'll see more and more ILS approaches move to RNAV as the primary approach rather than traditional radio's, although the "station based" navigation is not dying, it is just being replaced with other technologies like WAAS.

Comment: @jamesqf well. altough I dont know much about how much avionics the bush pilots have. I think they still use navigation aids for navigaiton and for landing at major airports like PABE.

Comment: @RonBeyer you are right. I was talking specifically about how pilots will aim towards the runways

Comment: "Station-based navigation is literally dying" this is a considerable exaggeration.

Comment: @0xdd exaggration? The FAA has been progressively closing them for a long time and they are finally planning to close almost all of them and WAAS is being improved! They will die in less than a decade!

Comment: That's cool, but there are large swaths of the world not regulated by the FAA (as well as admittedly small areas in the US) which will continue having station-based nav for a while to come.

Comment: "Almost all of them"?  No, about half of VORs in the Eastern US that were deemed redundant; coverage won't be materially affected.  And they're not taking out ILS systems either; they're just not putting in new ones (for GA).  They do seem to be killing NDBs outside Alaska, but that's no bug loss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are well on their way but it will never be a direct requirement per say. [The regulations state](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=ae21a142e1d5d86d12a58b1472c62fa2&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10.3.7.3&idno=14)

> (2) Two-way radio communication and **navigation equipment suitable for
>   the route to be flown.**

In many places a traditional VOR, DME, NDB or ADF may suffice as suitable navigation equipment however the FAA now has lower altitude GPS routes as well as many [LPV approaches out there](https://www.faasafety.gov/gslac/ALC/course_content.aspx?cID=38&sID=247&preview=true) that are coming on line. Generally LPV approaches have lower minimums than their non precision radio beacon counterparts. Thus going into an airport that often sees weather may only be possible with an LPV capable (WAAS) GPS. In turn your operations may be severely limited without GPS moving forward.

The FAA will likely never institute a regulation that says something like *all aircraft have to have IFR capable GPS' on board* as thats not really how they regulate things. Eventually if they were to drop all ground based radio nav aids in order to be compliant with the above regulation everyone wishing to fly IFR would need to have an IFR legal GPS on board.

---

For the record "back country" airports are far more likely to have a GPS approach than a ground based radio approach as their may be no facility near by and GPS approaches can be simpler to maintain and add to an existing field.